# confused about javascript code "require('./config/passport')(passport);"

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am fairly new to javascript and am trying to make a simple login restful api with the passport middleware. I know that when i do require('xxxxx'); I am bringing a module in for use.

I found some code online and it has this line
"require('./config/passport')(passport);"

I am wondering what it does and how this line differs from just doing
"require(passport);"?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ./config/passport is something in your local file structure.  Look at what is does.  It clearly returns a function that expects passport as an argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass parameters when requiring modules in node.js.
Simplified example:

*my-console.js*

```
function myConsole(message) {
    console.log(message);
}

module.exports = myConsole;
```

*some-other-file.js*

```
require('./my-console.js')('hey there!');
```

The above line will require `my-console.js`, pass the `'hey there'` string and execute `myConsole` function which takes `'hey there'` as it's parameter.

Comment: thanks so much!, this answers a ton fo questions that i had about the example code that i found online